# Pidfile of the delayed job is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am running delayed_job to run couple of tasks. But due to some reason my delayed_job just stops responding. So I am trying to monitor delayed_job using monit. I am not able to find out the pidfile of the delayed_job. How to I find the pidfile of the delayed_job? Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the tmp directory of your codebase: `tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid`